# Leaflet with GitHub Pages - not rendering

Tags: javascript, github, leaflet, github-pages

I have a simple webpage into which I have embedded a basic leaflet map. When I try to publish this via my GitHub Pages website, the leaflet map won't render (everything else is fine).

GitHub Pages spec says it supports JS and this shouldn't be a problem as it's an API. I have tried to use a downloaded version of leaflet (.css and .js files uploaded to my gh-pages repository), but still nothing.

Anyone have any ideas why this isn't working? Is this what GitHub Pages means when it says that it will host "static" webpages (no APIs, no JS interactivity)?

Comment: Any errors in your browser console?

Comment: Your repository url can be very useful.

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT**

Leaflet now [officially recommends](http://leafletjs.com/download.html) `unpkg` CDN which does support `https`:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@0.7.7/dist/leaflet.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@0.7.7/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
```

or

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.3/dist/leaflet.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
```

---

**Original answer**

There is a chance you are just facing a "mixed content" issue (resources from `HTTP` protocol trying to be loaded on a page accessed through secure `HTTPS` protocol).

Please note that GitHub pages for recent sites [now enforce `HTTPS` protocol](https://help.github.com/articles/securing-your-github-pages-site-with-https/):

> HTTPS enforcement is required for GitHub Pages sites created after June 15, 2016 and using a `github.io` domain.

This means that even if you manually type `http://my-site.github.io`, you will be automatically redirected to `https://my-site.github.io`.

The official Leaflet CDN does not support `HTTPS` protocol as of today unfortunately.

However, you can use alternative CDN's that do support `HTTPS`, e.g. [cdnjs](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/leaflet):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.0.0-rc.1/leaflet.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.0.0-rc.1/leaflet.js"></script>
```

But it is strange it still does not work when you try to use local (downloaded) scripts?

**Note:**

GitHub Pages serving only "static" webpages means that they cannot be dynamically generated server-side, e.g. through PHP. However you are free to use client-side code (JavaScript). E.g., Leaflet official website is actually hosted on GitHub.