# Geojson Layers bind to Leaflet Map locally, but when uploaded to github pages they do not render

Tags: github, leaflet, geojson

The leaflet map binds to the two geojson files just fine locally, but it does not render when I upload the document to github. The leaflet base map loads fine.

I tried the solution listed here: [Leaflet with GitHub Pages - not rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38136637/leaflet-with-github-pages-not-rendering)

But it had no apparent effect.

Thanks!

Comment: We can't help fix your code unless you show us what it is. Please see [ask] and how to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - the leaflet scripts were in HTTPS, but the jquery was not. I updated it and it works great!

Before:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css"/>
<script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3-respond-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

After:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://npmcdn.com/leaflet@1.0.0-rc.2/dist/leaflet.css" />
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/leaflet@1.0.0-rc.2/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3-respond-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```